# How to remove duplicate files when files are drag and drop in a react component using HTML drag and drop

Tags: reactjs, drag-and-drop, duplicates, components, dropzone

I have a drag and drop React component that is written in pure HTML. The component allows users to drag and drop one or multiple files. As soon as the files are dropped in the dropzone, the file names are displayed under the dropzone along with the 'x' cross button to remove any of the dropped files, as shown in the screenshot below:

[image]

This component only displays unique files. It means if duplicate files are dragged and dropped, the screen only displays those files one time. However, somewhere in my code, the duplicate files are retained and this is where the problem is that if I remove a file from the UI and assume that it was dropped multiple times, that file keep appearing again and again whenever I remove it from the UI. It keeps on appearing as many times as I dragged and dropped it in the dropzone. This is the problem I am unable to solve in my code.

I want this code to be updated such that if a file is dropped multiple times, it should be displayed just ones (which is already happening) but also when I remove that file from the UI, it should not appear again.

Below I am providing my entire App.js and App.css which you can easily copy-paste and run the behavior if you want:

App.js:

```
import React, { useRef, useState, useEffect } from "react";
import "./App.css";

function App() {
  const fileInputRef = useRef();
  const [selectedFiles, setSelectedFiles] = useState([]);
  const [validFiles, setValidFiles] = useState([]);
  const [unsupportedFiles, setUnsupportedFiles] = useState([]);
  const [errorMessage, setErrorMessage] = useState("");

  // useEffect Hook that removes stops duplicate files to be displayed
  useEffect(() => {
    let filteredArr = selectedFiles.reduce((acc, current) => {
      const x = acc.find((item) => item.name === current.name);
      if (!x) {
        return acc.concat([current]);
      } else {
        return acc;
      }
    }, []);
    setValidFiles([...filteredArr]);
  }, [selectedFiles]);

  // fileDrop method that access all the files which are being dragged and sends to handleFiles method
  const fileDrop = (e) => {
    preventDefault(e);
    const files = e.dataTransfer.files;
    if (files.length) {
      handleFiles(files);
    }
  };

  // fileSelected method that sends the files to handleFiles
  const filesSelected = () => {
    if (fileInputRef.current.files.length) {
      handleFiles(fileInputRef.current.files);
    }
  };

  // handleFiles method that receives all the files being dragged
  // validates if the files are of correct type
  // sets the selectedFiles state if valid or sets errorMessage state variable
  const handleFiles = (files) => {
    for (let i = 0; i < files.length; i++) {
      if (validateFile(files[i])) {
        setSelectedFiles((prevArray) => [...prevArray, files[i]]);
      } else {
        files[i]["invalid"] = true;
        setSelectedFiles((prevArray) => [...prevArray, files[i]]);
        setErrorMessage("File type not permitted");
        setUnsupportedFiles((prevArray) => [...prevArray, files[i]]);
      }
    }
  };

  // method that holds the valid allowed file types and checks if each of the file is valid or not
  const validateFile = (file) => {
    const validTypes = [
      "image/jpeg",
      "image/jpg",
      "image/png",
      "image/gif",
      "image/x-icon",
    ];
    if (validTypes.indexOf(file.type) === -1) {
      return false;
    }

    return true;
  };

  // method that receives the file name and handles the deletion of the file from all state variables.
  const removeFile = (name) => {
    const index = validFiles.findIndex((e) => e.name === name);
    const index2 = selectedFiles.findIndex((e) => e.name === name);
    const index3 = unsupportedFiles.findIndex((e) => e.name === name);
    validFiles.splice(index, 1);
    selectedFiles.splice(index2, 1);
    setValidFiles([...validFiles]);
    setSelectedFiles([...selectedFiles]);
    if (index3 !== -1) {
      unsupportedFiles.splice(index3, 1);
      setUnsupportedFiles([...unsupportedFiles]);
    }
  };

  // methods to prevent default browser bahavior on dragOver, dragEnter and dragLeave
  const preventDefault = (e) => {
    e.preventDefault();
  };

  const dragOver = (e) => {
    preventDefault(e);
  };

  const dragEnter = (e) => {
    preventDefault(e);
  };

  const dragLeave = (e) => {
    preventDefault(e);
  };

  // final HTML returned by the App component
  return (
    <div>
      <p className="title">React Drag and Drop Image Upload</p>
      <div className="content">
        <>
          <div className="container">
            <div
              className="drop-container"
              onDragOver={dragOver}
              onDragEnter={dragEnter}
              onDragLeave={dragLeave}
              onDrop={fileDrop}
            >
              <div className="drop-message">
                Drag & Drop files here or click to select file(s)
              </div>
              <input
                ref={fileInputRef}
                className="file-input"
                type="file"
                multiple
                onChange={filesSelected}
              />
            </div>
            <div className="file-display-container">
              {validFiles.map((data, i) => (
                <div className="file-status-bar" key={i}>
                  <div>
                    <span
                      className={`file-name ${
                        data.invalid ? "file-error" : ""
                      }`}
                    >
                      {data.name}
                    </span>

                    {data.invalid && (
                      <span className="file-error-message">
                        ({errorMessage})
                      </span>
                    )}
                  </div>
                  <div
                    className="file-remove"
                    onClick={() => removeFile(data.name)}
                  >
                    X
                  </div>
                </div>
              ))}
            </div>
          </div>
        </>
      </div>
    </div>
  );
}

export default App;
```

App.css:

```
.title {
    font-size: 2rem;
    text-align: center !important;
    margin-top: 10%;
    color: #4aa1f3;
    font-weight: bold;
}

.content {
    background-color: white;
    min-height: 100vh;
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: column;
    align-items: center;
    justify-content: center;
}

.file-input {
    display: none;
}

.container {
    transform: translateY(-100%);
}

.container p {
    color: red;
    text-align: center;
}

.drop-container {
    display: flex;
    align-items: center;
    justify-content: center;
    margin: 0;
    width: 800px;
    height: 200px;
    border: 4px dashed #4aa1f3;
}

.drop-message {
    text-align: center;
    color: #4aa1f3;
    font-family: Arial;
    font-size: 20px;
}

.file-display-container {
    position: fixed;
    width: 805px;
}

.file-status-bar {
    width: 100%;
    vertical-align: top;
    margin-top: 10px;
    margin-bottom: 20px;
    position: relative;
    line-height: 50px;
    height: 50px;
}

.file-status-bar>div {
    overflow: hidden;
}

.file-name {
    display: inline-block;
    vertical-align: top;
    margin-left: 50px;
    color: #4aa1f3;
}

.file-error {
    display: inline-block;
    vertical-align: top;
    margin-left: 50px;
    color: #9aa9bb;
}

.file-error-message {
    color: red;
}

.file-remove {
    position: absolute;
    top: 20px;
    right: 10px;
    line-height: 15px;
    cursor: pointer;
    color: red;
    margin-right: -10px;
}
```

Thank you so much for the help and support.

Answer (score 0):

I was able to implement a logic in two of my functions to handle this duplication. The first function I updated is the fileDrop function and the similar logic I wrote in the second function "filesSelected" as well to do the same thing if user browse for the files instead of drag-n-drop.

```
const fileDrop = (e) => {
    preventDefault(e);
    const files = e.dataTransfer.files;

    if (files.length) {
      let filteredArray = [];
      for (var index = 0; index < files.length; index++) {
        let exists = false;
        for (var i = 0; i < selectedFiles.length; i++) {
          if (selectedFiles[i].name === files[index].name) {
            exists = true;
            break;
          }
        }
        if (!exists) {
          filteredArray.push(files[index]);
        }
      }
      handleFiles(filteredArray);
    }
  };

  const filesSelected = () => {
    const files = fileInputRef.current.files;
    if (files.length) {
      let filteredArray = [];
      for (var index = 0; index < files.length; index++) {
        let exists = false;
        for (var i = 0; i < selectedFiles.length; i++) {
          if (selectedFiles[i].name === files[index].name) {
            exists = true;
            break;
          }
        }
        if (!exists) {
          filteredArray.push(files[index]);
        }
      }
      handleFiles(filteredArray);
    }
  };
```

As you can see in both the functions, I am doing following things:

1. Looping through all the files user has selected or dragged-n-dropped
2. For each file in the loop, setting "exists" variable to false
3. For each file in the loop, running a nested loop for all the files I already have in the selectedFiles array
4. In the nested loop, for each of the files in the selectedFiles array, I am comparing if the name of that file is equal to file name currently iterated in the outer loop (files array).
5. If the condition is true, the "exists" variable is set to true and inner loop is terminated and outer loop moves to the next file in the files array.
6. If the condition is false, that means the "exists" variable is false which means the new selected or dragged file does not exist in the selectedFiles array; hence I push it to the new filteredArray array.
7. Once the outer loop is completed, we have only those files in the filteredArray which are not already there in the selectedFiles array and therefore I am passing thefilteredArray to handleFiles method which will always have unique files in it.